# Grabbing a specific value from a List of Entitiy

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio, listbox

I load specific column values to a list through LINQ and i would like to grab specific instances of those. Here is the code for my page load.

```
 Public Sub CheckRO_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 Dim dc As New DataWorldDataContext.DataWorldDataContext
 Dim nonMatchingDealerID As New List(Of DataWorldDataContext.seanRFMatchTest)

    nonMatchingDealerID = (From z In dc.seanRFMatchTests Select z).ToList

    For Each item In nonMatchingDealerID

        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ContractDealerID & " " & item.ServiceDealerID & " " &  item.intRepairFacilCode & " " & item.chrPgmCode & " " & item.chrRONum & " " & item.chvFacilityName)

    Next

End Sub
```

On selectedIndexChange of the ListBox, i would like to apply the item.ContractDealerID value to a textbox.

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.?????????????

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would consider using a data grid or listview control.

To answer your question: You need to use the **SelectedItem** property.

Example:

```
    Dim _SelectedValue As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SelectedValue) Then
        TextBox1.Text = _SelectedValue.Substring(0, _SelectedValue.IndexOf(" "))
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    End If
```